# Using Query with IMPORTRANGE and comparison of dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I created a Google Form that employees complete, The data goes into the main sheet in a spreadsheet. I then want to split that data into separate sheets according to the date in one of the columns. In my separate sheets, I've entered the dates that I want included in cells A1 and B1. This is where I"m stuck.

Can someone look at this and tell me where I went wrong?

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gYzU1Tt-
0BNCZDBST06ETNHoE0pgkUdTpQctMqDW-1A/edit#gid=1240808529","'Form Responses 10'!A:JQ"),
"WHERE ET>=date """&text(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and ET<=date """
&text(B1,yyyy-mm-dd")&""")
```

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here.

1. When using `query` with `importrange`, the imported columns must be referred to as Col1, Col2, Col3, etc, according to their positions in the imported range. Your reference "ET" will not work.
2. You have a mess of quotation marks going on. Remember that the query string can contain single quotes. Instead of `"WHERE ET>=date """&text(...` it is easier to write `"WHERE ET>=date '"&text(...` because single quotes inside of double quotes need not be escaped.
3. You are missing a quotation mark in `text(B1,yyyy-mm-dd")`.
4. The very end of query string is supposed to be an escaped quotation mark enclosed by quotation marks on both ends. Your `"""` is not enough for that. Save yourself headache and use `"'"`, as advised by 2.
5. When a query is formed by concatenation like this, it is **highly** advisable to put it in a separate cell. E.g., your cell C1 can contain just the query string

```
="WHERE Col2>=date '"&text(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2<=date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"
```

and then some other cell has `=query(importrange(...), C1)`. This approach simplifies debugging because you get to see what the query is before its attempted execution.